# Windows7 explorer context strip hook?

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, windows-shell

Hy everybody,

I'm wondering if it's possible to add a new button via C++ or C# to windows 7 explorer "context strip"(don't know if this is correct name) - like on picture below.

My reason for this is because a lot of times I'm switching on&off "Show hidden files, folders and drives" functionality under Tools->Folder option->View. Therefore i want to simplify this process with a click of a button.

I was looking into `ShellExecteEx` function, but I am not sure I can do that. Can Anybody direct me in right direction?

[image: explorer]

thanks,
regards

Answer (score 1):

I highly recommend using AutoIt for this task. Second URL comes complete with examples of how to insert buttons in various programs - however, be sure to read complete topic for misc. updates to the provided code.

See:

1. http://www.autoitscript.com/forum/index.php?showtopic=9517

Btw: I misread topic to begin with; gui 'context' related material in Windows is often taken to deal with right-click menus

Edit: limit on urls for new users on Stack Overflow mean I had to cut out some of less essential links - google away.

Comment: thanks for the link. It looks interesting, I'll certainly look into it.
Yeah, I named it 'context strip' because the commands change depending on where are you in explorer, so it's almost like right-click except only with most used commands and it's always visible

Answer (score 0):

To answer part of the question, I think it is possible as for quite some time we've seen small programs to add a "New Folder" button to the explorer. I think those still works with Win 7.
Look at http://tools.tortoisesvn.net/StExBar for example

[Edit] Forgot to clarify that Source Code for StExBar is on Google Code

Comment: Thanks, I thought of that to, But it is possible to add only one button somewhere on explorer? Because I don't want the whole toolbar to take my vertical screen estate just for one button.

Comment: This is another one http://www.baxbex.com/images/shoots/bxnewfolder.html that you can test on Win7 and see the result